# Change paintEvent color with stylesheet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside2, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to subclass a `QCheckBox` to inherit its behavior, but subclassing its `paintEvent` so that I can draw it like Android's toggle button. Is there a way to allow its stylesheet to determine the color it draws with?

In the example below I'm drawing an ellipse with a color I made as a qt `Property` in the hopes that I could do something like `inst.setStyleSheet("MyCheckBox {MyColor: red;}")` to make it red, but it does nothing. Is this possible?

```
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class MyCheckBox(QtWidgets.QCheckBox):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyCheckBox, self).__init__(parent)

        self._myColor = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 0)

    def myColor(self):
        return self._myColor

    def setMyColor(self, qcolor):
        self._myColor = qcolor

    MyColor = QtCore.Property(QtGui.QColor, myColor, setMyColor)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        paint = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        paint.setBrush(self._myColor)
        paint.drawEllipse(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) points out the syntax is `qproperty-<property name>`.

```
MyCheckBox {qproperty-MyColor: red;}
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Do you know if there's a way to set a custom name for it instead of always having `qproperty` as a prefix? Like `MyCheckBox {MyColor: red;}` ?

Comment: @GreenCell No, there is no way.